# Neo4j - dont return starting node

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm doing the following cypher query in Neo4j:

```
START a = node(4107) 
MATCH a-[:AttractionFor]->b-[r:Brother]-c-[:AttractionFor]->d 
WHERE (r.distance? <= 25)
RETURN distinct d
```

This return the value of a also, which I don't need. I tried `a<>d` and `a.name <> b.name` but I get the same result. Also in webadmin it returns nothing (I'm using Everyman's PHP library for neo4j).

Comment: Can you explain your graph a bit more, or maybe post something on console.neo4j.org -- I'm not sure what you mean by "this returns the value of a also", because there's no a being returned. Do you mean there's a cycle?

Comment: he means the query returns the value of A as well. the path cycles itself into the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, cypher will not go into an already traversed vertex. this means, that if you have stated in the match section

```
a-[:AttractionFor]->b-[r:Brother]-c-[:AttractionFor]->d
```

than the D will never be the A. do you have maybe vertices with the same names/values? could you provide us with the graph data/design?

Comment: actually i resolved the problem. i just mispelled something. it does go back to starting node, but a <> d works for that. Thanks anyway